# Android Studio throws error with empty project

Tags: android, android-studio

I get that error:

style attribute 'android:attr/metaButtonBarStyle' not found

I get it on a new empty project on a just installed version of Android Studio.

I've tried rebuilding the project, adding the property metaButtonBarStyle in the generated values.xml file, disabling AAPT2 on gradle-wrapper.properties with android.enableAapt2=false, I've tried uninstalling plugins and Android Studio, starting with a just-installed version of Android Studio with an empty project and I still get the error.

this are my dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

could anybody help me with this?

Comment: how did you define metaButtonBarStyle? where did you define your style? show your code. Also your style isn't android style so you mustn't set android:attr/....

Comment: It sounds like it would be an issue with the new project template in Android Studio. Can you share the project (zip it and upload it somewhere) and also say which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: The problem is that metaButtonBarStyle is a normal attribute, not a platform one, that's why saying "android:attr/metaButtonBarStyle" is not working. It should be "@attr/metaButtonBarStyle" insted.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading which SDK you're using may help unless you need a particular one.

I know when I was using Android's SDK with the Unity game engine I had to go in and delete/rename a folder to trigger Unity to download versions of those files that worked, I don't know if a similar auto-repair is available in Android Studio but if there is you might want to locate where metaButtonBarStyle should be and rename the parent folder.